# Domain issue with tomcat

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, redirect

I have deployed a java based website on my VPS. It successfully deployed and working correctly. I have defined a redirect rule to redirect from root to sub folder. The issue right now I am facing is,

> if I put domain.com -> redirects to domain.com/pages/shopIndex (shows
>   page correctly)

and

> when I put www.domain.com -> redirects to
>   www.domain.com/pages/shopIndex (shows 404)

I am not understanding this strange behavior because I have added alias for domain.com to www.domain.com in my httpd.conf

This is how my virtual host file look like:

```
<VirtualHost 192.169.235.118:80>
  ServerName domain.parentDomain.in
  ServerAlias domain.com www.domain.com www.domain.parentDomain.in
  DocumentRoot /path_to/domain.com
  ServerAdmin admin@admin
  UseCanonicalName Off
  CustomLog /path_to/domain.parentDomain.in combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Can anyone help me to find the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution for this problem, there is `Alias` tag for `server.xml` file where we can put `Alias` for host we want to represent.

This is how I solved the issue (in `server.xml` inside `host` tag):

```
<Alias>www.domain.com</Alias>
```

Comment: You shouldn't bother setting the hostname in Tomcat if you don't really care what it is. Just use the default host for everything.

Comment: Yes I know @ChristopherSchultz but the thing is it may possible that end user may enter `www.domain.com` / `domain.com` which eventually converted into `http://www.domain.com` / `http://domain.com`, due to this apache tomcat may not be able to get correct path. Also I forgot to tell that I have mentioned host=domain.com in `server.xml` file in host tag that could be the reason it was not getting redirected to correct path and I was getting 404 error.